# How to make my win32 app show right mouse clicks

Tags: c++, winapi

This is what i Have so far.

```
      case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);

            GetClientRect (hwnd, &rect);

            GetWindowRect(hwnd, &size);

            width = size.right - size.left;
            itoa(width, Swidth, 10);
            height = size.bottom - size.top;
            itoa(height, Sheight, 10);
            itoa(rect.bottom, sBottom, 10);
            itoa(rect.top, sTop, 10);
            itoa(rect.left, sLeft, 10);
            itoa(rect.right, sRight, 10);

            TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, "Here is my width: ", 18);
            TextOut(hdc, 125, 0, Swidth, 5);
            TextOut(hdc, 175, 0, "Here is my height: ", 18);
            TextOut(hdc, 300, 0, Sheight, 4);

            TextOut(hdc, 0, 20, sBottom, strlen(sBottom));
            TextOut(hdc, 50, 20, sTop, strlen(sTop));
            TextOut(hdc, 100, 20, sRight, strlen(sRight));
            TextOut(hdc, 150, 20, sLeft, strlen(sLeft));

            TextOut(hdc, 0, 40, "Right Button Clicked: ", 23);
            itoa(rightButtonClicked, SrightButtonClicked, 10);
            TextOut(hdc, 150, 40, SrightButtonClicked, strlen(SrightButtonClicked));

            if(rightButtonClicked > 20)
                TextOut(hdc, 0, 60, SrightButtonClicked, strlen(SrightButtonClicked));

            EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;

      case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
          return 0;

      case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
          rightButtonClicked++;
          return 0
```

Now I'm not sure what I"m doing wrong but I'm supposed to make it output the number of times I right click within the windows. The counter I have for rightButtonClicked incremetns but it won't display properly. Yes this is homework and I have researched the topic quite a bit so I'm looking for a little help.

Comment: Where does `SrightButtonChanged` get declared and updated?

Comment: Your window doesn't know when the counter increments, so it's probably not updated. Try invalidating needed parts of the window on `WM_RBUTTONDOWN`.

Comment: Simple solution: Just add a call to `UpdateWindow(hwnd)` in your `case WM_RBUTTONDOWN` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145167(v=vs.85).aspx) It's registering the clicks, but not told to paint.

Comment: @WiredPrairie You mean `InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, TRUE);`. `UpdateWindow` only forces immediate updates of already invalidated regions.

Comment: @john -- add that too. :)